# Car lurched slightly after changing rear brake pad

Tags: brakes, maintenance, mazda, suspension, mazda-3

Long story short, after jacking up right rear, taking wheel off, putting back on and lowering, when I sat in the driver's seat, I felt a sudden further lowering (drop) in the right rear side. Could that be the shocks compressing another notch as a response to my additional weight in the driver's seat? I've changed brakes in several cars prior and never experienced this. This was the first time changing brakes in this car, Mazda 3 Hatch.

I drove it around the block and it seems fine, just curious.

Comment: Welcome to the site, btw :o)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the car is driving fine and sits fine (looks to be level on level ground), I'd suggest there aren't any issues. More than likely the car just settled after having the suspension completely extended. If there aren't any unusual noises, and the car stops and rides fine, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: Follow up: everything was just fine. :)